# Cannot loging because of ubuntu--vg-root: clean - Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS

Tags: 16.04, login

After a reboot I could not log back in via the GUI.  I got the black screen with a flash of text saying:

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, XXX/XXXfiles, XXX/XXX
```

and then reverts back to the login screen.

I did the 'uselvmetad = 0' fix and ran 'sudo update-initramfs -u -k all'

THis got rid of the lvmetad errors, but not the 'ubuntu--vg-root: clean' error.  From what I can tell people have fixed it by running 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop', but this did not work for me.  I also tried 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity' with no luck.

Does anyone know of anything else that I could try?

Comment: That's not an error and where did you see the suggestion to reinstall?

Comment: These showed up when I had an issue where I couldn't login because my login screen kept restarting.  I saw some posts where others had both problems as well and some fixed it by reinstalling the desktop.

Anyways, I found that the actual problem was that the ownership had been changed to ~/.XAuthority

Answer (score 0):

I found that the actual problem was that the ownership had been changed to ~/.XAuthority and I had to chown it back to my user.